# Variance calculated with two methods returns different results in Python

Tags: python, math, variance

I wanted to calculate the variance for a distribution of discrete values using two different methods, to prove they return identical results:

```
1. σ**2 = <j**2> - <j>**2
2. σ**2 = <(Δj)**2> = Σ(Δj)**2 *P(j)
```

Here's my code:

```py
j = [14,15,16,22,24,25]
Nj = [1,1,3,2,2,5]
N = sum(Nj)

Pj = [Nj[i]/N for i in range(len(j))]

j_mean = sum(Pj[i]*j[i] for i in range(len(j)))
j_sqmean = sum(Pj[i]*j[i]**2 for i in range(len(j)))

var1 = j_mean**2 - j_sqmean
var2 = sum((j[i]-j_mean)*Nj[i] for i in range(len(j)))

print(var1,var2)
```

For some reason `var1 != var2` is the result and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong with my code.

Comment: `var1` is computed by a method well-known to be numerically unstable.

Comment: I suppose all typos: `Nj[i]` in `var2 = ` should be `Pj[i]`. The difference in `var1 = ` is the wrong way around. `**2` is missing over the difference in `var2 = `.

Comment: You reiterated a mathematical identity: the 1st moment about the mean is 0.  When you computed `var2`, you forgot to square the terms.  When you post a question, remember to include the actual and expected outputs; the actual output would have reduced teh response time to seconds.  VTC as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your two formulas wrong. Change it to:

```
var1 = j_sqmean -j_mean**2 
var2 = sum((j[i]-j_mean)**2 * Pj[i] for i in range(len(j)))

print(var1,var2)
# 18.571428571428555 18.57142857142857
```